# Sqoop-Hive Import

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I am facing one issue while importing data from `rdbms` into hive via `sqoop`. Please do not mark this as duplicate

I am importing data from oracle 12c db into Hive. The data is getting created inside hdfs but hive tables are not getting created i.e a folder gets created inside /user/hive/warehouse in the name of the table which i am importing, but when I go to hive editor and check for this table it doesn't show me.

However if I create the schema of this table before importing the data (create table ..) and now if I import my data by running sqoop import the data is found inside both hdfs and hive tables as well.

Below is the details of what I am doing

**1. Initialising**

```
    usermod -a -G supergroup venkat
    export SQOOP_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop
    export HIVE_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hive
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/ojdbc7.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hive/lib/*
    export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs
    export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

**2. Running sqoop import**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl --username BDD1 --password oracle123 --table EMP -m 1 --hive-import --hive-table emp
```

Following are the logs:

```
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Could not rename /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/c6516678b105260186a4b5daf7552fcb/EMP.java to /root/./EMP.java
    16/04/15 18:10:10 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/c6516678b105260186a4b5daf7552fcb/EMP.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Scanning for .class files in directory: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/c6516678b105260186a4b5daf7552fcb
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Got classfile: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/c6516678b105260186a4b5daf7552fcb/EMP.class -> EMP.class
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG orm.CompilationManager: Finished writing jar file /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/c6516678b105260186a4b5daf7552fcb/EMP.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Got cached connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl/BDD1
    16/04/15 18:10:10 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Caching released connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl/BDD1
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Got cached connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl/BDD1
    16/04/15 18:10:10 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Caching released connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl/BDD1
    16/04/15 18:10:10 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of EMP
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Checking for existing class: EMP
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Attempting to load jar through URL: jar:file:/tmp/sqoop-root/compile/c6516678b105260186a4b5daf7552fcb/EMP.jar!/
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Previous classloader is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5a42bbf4
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Testing class in jar: EMP
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Loaded jar into current JVM: jar:file:/tmp/sqoop-root/compile/c6516678b105260186a4b5daf7552fcb/EMP.jar!/
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Added classloader for jar /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/c6516678b105260186a4b5daf7552fcb/EMP.jar: java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader@37d3d232
    16/04/15 18:10:10 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG db.DBConfiguration: Securing password into job credentials store
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Got cached connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl/BDD1
    16/04/15 18:10:10 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Caching released connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl/BDD1
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob: Using table class: EMP
    16/04/15 18:10:10 DEBUG mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob: Using InputFormat: class com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.db.OracleDataDrivenDBInputFormat
    16/04/15 18:10:11 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/sqoop-1.4.6-cdh5.5.1.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/ojdbc6.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/sqoop-1.4.6-cdh5.5.1.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/sqoop-1.4.6-cdh5.5.1.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-jackson.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/avro-mapred-hadoop2.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-avro.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/xz-1.0.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/jackson-annotations-2.3.1.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/fastutil-6.3.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/ojdbc6.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/avro.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/kite-data-mapreduce.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/kite-data-hive.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/kite-hadoop-compatibility.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-encoding.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/kite-data-core.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-column.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-common.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/ojdbc7.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-hadoop.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-format.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 DEBUG mapreduce.JobBase: Adding to job classpath: file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/sqoop/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
    16/04/15 18:10:11 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at bigdata/10.103.25.39:8032
    16/04/15 18:10:19 DEBUG db.DBConfiguration: Fetching password from job credentials store
    16/04/15 18:10:19 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
    16/04/15 18:10:19 DEBUG db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: Creating input split with lower bound '1=1' and upper bound '1=1'
    16/04/15 18:10:19 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
    16/04/15 18:10:20 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1460530815947_0198
    16/04/15 18:10:21 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1460530815947_0198
    16/04/15 18:10:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://bigdata:8088/proxy/application_1460530815947_0198/
    16/04/15 18:10:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1460530815947_0198
    16/04/15 18:10:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1460530815947_0198 running in uber mode : false
    16/04/15 18:10:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    16/04/15 18:10:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
    16/04/15 18:10:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1460530815947_0198 completed successfully
    16/04/15 18:10:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
        File System Counters
            FILE: Number of bytes read=0
            FILE: Number of bytes written=137941
            FILE: Number of read operations=0
            FILE: Number of large read operations=0
            FILE: Number of write operations=0
            HDFS: Number of bytes read=87
            HDFS: Number of bytes written=12
            HDFS: Number of read operations=4
            HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
            HDFS: Number of write operations=2
        Job Counters 
            Launched map tasks=1
            Other local map tasks=1
            Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=4157
            Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
            Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=4157
            Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=4157
            Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=2128384
        Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=3
            Map output records=3
            Input split bytes=87
            Spilled Records=0
            Failed Shuffles=0
            Merged Map outputs=0
            GC time elapsed (ms)=56
            CPU time spent (ms)=2240
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=213250048
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2180124672
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=134742016
        File Input Format Counters 
            Bytes Read=0
        File Output Format Counters 
            Bytes Written=12
    16/04/15 18:10:39 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 12 bytes in 28.3024 seconds (0.424 bytes/sec)
    16/04/15 18:10:39 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 3 records.
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Restoring classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5a42bbf4
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG hive.HiveImport: Hive.inputTable: EMP
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG hive.HiveImport: Hive.outputTable: emp
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: Using column names query: SELECT t.* FROM EMP t WHERE 1=0
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM EMP t WHERE 1=0
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Got cached connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl/BDD1
    16/04/15 18:10:39 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Using fetchSize for next query: 1000
    16/04/15 18:10:39 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM EMP t WHERE 1=0
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column EMP_ID of type [12, 5, 0]
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column EMP_NAME of type [12, 100, 0]
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Caching released connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl/BDD1
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG hive.TableDefWriter: Create statement: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emp` ( `EMP_ID` STRING, `EMP_NAME` STRING) COMMENT 'Imported by sqoop on 2016/04/15 18:10:39' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\012' STORED AS TEXTFILE
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG hive.TableDefWriter: Load statement: LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://bigdata:8020/user/hdfs/EMP' INTO TABLE `emp`
    16/04/15 18:10:39 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG hive.HiveImport: Using in-process Hive instance.
    16/04/15 18:10:39 DEBUG util.SubprocessSecurityManager: Installing subprocess security manager

    Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.5.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
    OK
    Time taken: 0.782 seconds
    Loading data to table default.emp
    Table default.emp stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=12, rawDataSize=0]
    OK
    Time taken: 0.676 seconds
    You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
    [root@bigdatadev1 ~]#
```

**3. When I run the below sqoop import command, I get the following error (showing last few lines of logs)**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl --username BDD1 --password oracle123 --table EMP -m 1 --create-hive-table --hive-import --hive-table emp

    16/04/15 18:17:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://bigdata:8088/proxy/application_1460530815947_0200/
    16/04/15 18:17:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1460530815947_0200
    16/04/15 18:17:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1460530815947_0200 running in uber mode : false
    16/04/15 18:17:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    16/04/15 18:17:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
    16/04/15 18:17:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1460530815947_0200 completed successfully
    16/04/15 18:17:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
        File System Counters
            FILE: Number of bytes read=0
            FILE: Number of bytes written=137940
            FILE: Number of read operations=0
            FILE: Number of large read operations=0
            FILE: Number of write operations=0
            HDFS: Number of bytes read=87
            HDFS: Number of bytes written=12
            HDFS: Number of read operations=4
            HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
            HDFS: Number of write operations=2
        Job Counters 
            Launched map tasks=1
            Other local map tasks=1
            Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=4067
            Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
            Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=4067
            Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=4067
            Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=2082304
        Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=3
            Map output records=3
            Input split bytes=87
            Spilled Records=0
            Failed Shuffles=0
            Merged Map outputs=0
            GC time elapsed (ms)=58
            CPU time spent (ms)=2350
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=221048832
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2178715648
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=135790592
        File Input Format Counters 
            Bytes Read=0
        File Output Format Counters 
            Bytes Written=12
    16/04/15 18:17:19 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 12 bytes in 21.9242 seconds (0.5473 bytes/sec)
    16/04/15 18:17:19 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 3 records.
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Restoring classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5a42bbf4
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG hive.HiveImport: Hive.inputTable: EMP
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG hive.HiveImport: Hive.outputTable: emp
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: Using column names query: SELECT t.* FROM EMP t WHERE 1=0
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM EMP t WHERE 1=0
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Got cached connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl/BDD1
    16/04/15 18:17:19 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Using fetchSize for next query: 1000
    16/04/15 18:17:19 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM EMP t WHERE 1=0
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column EMP_ID of type [12, 5, 0]
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column EMP_NAME of type [12, 100, 0]
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Caching released connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl/BDD1
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG hive.TableDefWriter: Create statement: CREATE TABLE `emp` ( `EMP_ID` STRING, `EMP_NAME` STRING) COMMENT 'Imported by sqoop on 2016/04/15 18:17:19' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\012' STORED AS TEXTFILE
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG hive.TableDefWriter: Load statement: LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://bigdata:8020/user/hdfs/EMP' INTO TABLE `emp`
    16/04/15 18:17:19 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG hive.HiveImport: Using in-process Hive instance.
    16/04/15 18:17:19 DEBUG util.SubprocessSecurityManager: Installing subprocess security manager

    Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.5.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
    FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. AlreadyExistsException(message:Table emp already exists)
```

4.
Now when I create the schema of the table 'create table emp ...' and then import the data, I get the data inside my hdfs as well as hive tables.

Is it that sqoop can be used only if the table schema exists? It can't create a new table on it's own?

Am I missing something in my import command line. Please do not mark this as duplicate

Comment: but create table script ==> **CREATE TABLE `emp` ( `EMP_ID` STRING, `EMP_NAME` STRING) COMMENT 'Imported by sqoop on 2016/04/15 18:17:19' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\012' STORED AS TEXTFILE** is executed without any error. Just fire this command from hive shell and check if table is created or not

Comment: Yes dev, when i  run the script CREATE TABLE emp ( EMP_ID STRING, EMP_NAME STRING), the table gets created. Now if I run my sqoop import it populates the data inside the table

Answer (score 0):

Usually these errors are due to permission errors & mis-configuration. Considering this is not a incremental data ingestion, following should work.

I have added the warehouse-dir & hive-overwrite options. Please drop the existing emp table in Hive & execute the command below, replace path/to/dir with appropriate warehouse directory in hdfs.

```
  sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@bigdatadev2:1521/orcl --username BDD1 --password oracle123 --table EMP -m 1 --warehouse-dir "path/to/dir" --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table emp
```

Comment: Hi Ruben, I ran the command where i gave warehouse dir as /user/hive/warehouse as this is the place where my 'emp' folder gets created (No folder gets created inside /user/hdfs folder). But still no tables are getting created

Comment: @HardikGupta /user/hive/warehouse is a warehouse directory for hive, usually there is warehouse directory for sqoop as well. My assumption is, the table is not being dropped even when you execute the `drop table emp` because of permission error. You need to be careful and use the same user throughout the system to avoid such problems. First, I would check if the table is dropped; create & give /user/hdfs/data as warehouse-dir; use hdfs user to execute the sqoop command from command line; create & provide specific database name for emp table.